# Jest -- NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-flink, guava, elasticsearch-jest

I am following [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-real-time-stream-processing-pipeline-with-apache-flink-on-aws/) example  and trying to use Jest as client to put data to AWS ElasticSearch, and I am using Scala 2.11

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-core" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-scala_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-streaming-scala_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-shaded-hadoop2" % "1.4.0",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-yarn" % "1.3.2",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.6.2",
  "org.apache.flink" % "flink-clients_2.11" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-avro" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-connector-filesystem" % "1.3.2",
  "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-statebackend-rocksdb" % "1.3.2",
  "io.searchbox" % "jest" % "5.3.3",
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.113",
  "vc.inreach.aws" % "aws-signing-request-interceptor" % "0.0.20"
)
```

However, I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at com.google.common.reflect.TypeCapture.capture(TypeCapture.java:32)
    at com.google.common.reflect.TypeToken.<init>(TypeToken.java:117)
    at io.searchbox.core.Bulk$1.<init>(Bulk.java:96)
    at io.searchbox.core.Bulk.getData(Bulk.java:96)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.prepareRequest(JestHttpClient.java:116)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:64)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:60)
    at ElasticsearchJestSink.flushDocumentBuffer(ElasticsearchJestSink.java:96)
    at ElasticsearchJestSink.invoke(ElasticsearchJestSink.java:81)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSink.processElement(StreamSink.java:41)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.pushToOperator(OperatorChain.java:528)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:503)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.OperatorChain$CopyingChainingOutput.collect(OperatorChain.java:483)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:891)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.AbstractStreamOperator$CountingOutput.collect(AbstractStreamOperator.java:869)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.TimestampedCollector.collect(TimestampedCollector.java:51)
    at EventTimeJoinFunction$$anonfun$processElement2$1.apply(EventTimeJoinFunction.scala:54)
    at EventTimeJoinFunction$$anonfun$processElement2$1.apply(EventTimeJoinFunction.scala:53)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at EventTimeJoinFunction.processElement2(EventTimeJoinFunction.scala:53)
    at EventTimeJoinFunction.processElement2(EventTimeJoinFunction.scala:15)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.co.KeyedCoProcessOperator.processElement2(KeyedCoProcessOperator.java:85)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.io.StreamTwoInputProcessor.processInput(StreamTwoInputProcessor.java:269)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.TwoInputStreamTask.run(TwoInputStreamTask.java:91)
```

I also did the shade rule but it won't work

```
assemblyShadeRules in assembly := Seq(
  ShadeRule.rename("com.google.common.**" -> "shade.com.google.common.@1")
  .inLibrary("com.google.guava" % "guava" % "21.0")
  .inProject
)
```

I think jest is using guava 21.0 which is higher than 20.0 as suggested in other questions, but it still gets the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using flink 1.4, it has guava shaded to prevent this exact problem

Comment: @Xeli, I have tried 1.4.2 but still got the same error message.